# Oracle SQL Error ORA-00933 on INSERT in Lucee

Tags: oracle, lucee

Error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Attempting to INSERT a row using the following cfscript statement:

```
q.setSQL("
INSERT INTO SALES_OPTION_CHOICE (SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID, DESCRIP, ISDEFAULT, CODE, SALES_CHOICE_ID, PRICE) 
SELECT #r.SCOINDEX[i]#, sc.DESCRIP, #(data.isDefault == 'Y' ? "'Y'" : "NULL")#, sc.CODE, sc.ID, sc.PRICE
FROM SALES_CHOICE sc
WHERE sc.ID = #y.id[1]#
");
```

Results in

```
INSERT INTO SALES_OPTION_CHOICE (SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID, DESCRIP, ISDEFAULT, CODE, SALES_CHOICE_ID, PRICE) 
SELECT 25628, sc.DESCRIP, 'Y', sc.CODE, sc.ID, sc.PRICE
FROM SALES_CHOICE sc
WHERE sc.ID = 222
```

Other variants that also fail with error ORA-00933:

```
INSERT INTO SALES_OPTION_CHOICE (SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID, DESCRIP, ISDEFAULT, CODE, SALES_CHOICE_ID, PRICE, SEQ) 
SELECT 25628, DESCRIP, 'Y', CODE, ID, PRICE, NULL
FROM SALES_CHOICE
WHERE ID = 222
AND NOT ID in (
    SELECT SALES_CHOICE_ID 
    FROM SALES_OPTION_CHOICE l
    WHERE SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID = 25628
)

INSERT INTO SALES_OPTION_CHOICE (SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID, DESCRIP, ISDEFAULT, CODE, SALES_CHOICE_ID, PRICE, SEQ) 
SELECT 25628, DESCRIP, 'Y', CODE, ID, PRICE, NULL
FROM SALES_CHOICE
WHERE ID = 222

INSERT INTO SALES_OPTION_CHOICE (SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID, DESCRIP, ISDEFAULT, CODE, SALES_CHOICE_ID, PRICE, SEQ) 
SELECT 25628, DESCRIP, 'Y', CODE, ID, PRICE, NULL
FROM SALES_CHOICE
WHERE ID = 222

INSERT INTO SALES_OPTION_CHOICE (SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID, DESCRIP, ISDEFAULT, CODE, SALES_CHOICE_ID, PRICE) 
SELECT 25628 SCOINDEX, DESCRIP, 'Y' ISDEFAULT, CODE, ID, PRICE
FROM SALES_CHOICE
WHERE ID = 222

INSERT INTO SALES_OPTION_CHOICE (SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID, DESCRIP, ISDEFAULT, CODE, SALES_CHOICE_ID, PRICE) 
SELECT 25628 SCOINDEX, sc.DESCRIP, 'Y' ISDEFAULT, sc.CODE, sc.ID, sc.PRICE
FROM SALES_CHOICE sc
WHERE sc.ID = 222

INSERT INTO SALES_OPTION_CHOICE (SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID, DESCRIP, ISDEFAULT, CODE, SALES_CHOICE_ID, PRICE) 
SELECT 25628 SCOINDEX, sc.DESCRIP, 'Y' ISDEFAULT, sc.CODE, sc.ID, sc.PRICE
FROM SALES_CHOICE sc
WHERE sc.ID = 222;
```

I'm sure the issue is some small oversight on my part.  I've been battling this for hours now.  I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: ORA-00933 is: `SQL command not properly ended`, for those who (like me) aren't a walking encyclopaedia of Oracle error messages. @Teaspoon: please include the entire error message when asking questions on this (or any) forum.

Comment: Post your table DDL. As far i can see, your insert statement is correct.

Comment: `AND NOT ID in(..` should be changed to `AND id NOT in(...`.

Comment: @XING table DDL is proprietary so I won't be posting that.  Table name and all columns are upper case.

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question, but you really should use cfqueryparam / addParam on all variable query parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!  Apparently INSERT statements need to be wrapped in BEGIN - END;

```
q.setSQL("
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO SALES_OPTION_CHOICE (SALES_CONFIG_OPTION_ID, DESCRIP, ISDEFAULT, CODE, SALES_CHOICE_ID, PRICE) 
       SELECT #r.SCOINDEX[i]#, sc.DESCRIP, #(data.isDefault == 'Y' ? "'Y'" : "NULL")#, sc.CODE, sc.ID, sc.PRICE
       FROM SALES_CHOICE sc
       WHERE sc.ID = #y.id[1]#;
    END;
");
```